# Border Color Issue in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibarbuttonitem

Navigation Item background color is `Theme.maroonColor`

I am using https://github.com/mikeMTOL/UIBarButtonItem-Badge for Badge in `UIBarButtonItem`.

When I set

```
menuButton.badgeBGColor = UIColor(red: 242/255, green: 241/255, blue: 182/255, alpha: 1.0)
menuButton.badge.layer.borderWidth = 2
menuButton.badge.layer.borderColor = Theme.maroonColor.cgColor
menuButton.badgeFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12)
menuButton.shouldHideBadgeAtZero = true
menuButton.badgeTextColor = Theme.maroonColor
```

after the border color there is a line in the border which color is same as background color of badge's background. Its weird issue I never faced this before and don't know how to search this issue.

[image]

Comment: Are you testing on Simulator? If yes so could you make it full size... Window+1

Comment: It is full size 100%
I tested this on iPhone 6S same issue

Comment: Zoomed: https://monosnap.com/file/kekl96spaV9ASEQbhfClvEffwu0EkX

Comment: menuButton.badge.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: @Adnan .
Tried. but still same issue. :(

Comment: Try with other color. Will it happen again?

Comment: Yes same thing happening

Comment: can you post full code of this button? do you have yellow image? if yes, there is problem... its happening bcz yellow image is pixelated...

Comment: menuButton.badgeBGColor = UIColor(red: 242/255, green: 241/255, blue: 182/255, alpha: 1.0)
            menuButton.badge.layer.borderWidth = 2
            menuButton.badge.layer.borderColor = Theme.maroonColor.cgColor
            menuButton.badgeFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12)
            menuButton.shouldHideBadgeAtZero = true
            menuButton.badgeTextColor = Theme.maroonColor